# Recursion Factorial Function , How they are Calling a Function Without an Object or even Class name here?

Tags: java, function, recursion, factorial

I Am New to Java , but I have Learn a lot of concepts thoroughly and I Am enjoying it . But in the below Code part :

```
class Factorial {  
     int fact(int n) {  
         int result;  
         if ( n ==1) return 1;  
         result = fact (n-1) * n;  
         return result;  
     }  
}
```

I Have Understood the Logic but the Question is How I am Able to call a Function here Without Using any Reference Object .

```
result = fact (n-1) * n;
```

Why Object Initialization is Not Required Here .

Answer (score 3):

```
fact(n - 1)
```

is equivalent to

```
this.fact(n - 1)
```